# How can I use a button on one view controller to add text to a row in a table view in another view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

So I'm still pretty new to iOS and this is somewhat of an issue for me. I'm (trying) working on a practice app of sorts where text labels are displayed on the screen, if the user likes that text label, then they can favorite it. Then, all of the user's favorite text labels will appear in a table view. My question is how can I utilize a button to add a text label to a table view? Basically, I'm confused on how to make a favorites list. For more clarity, here is a very simple physical representation of my problem.

I want to go from this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3irmh.png

To this, when the user taps the button:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdSnP.png

And to be able to keep populating the table view whenever that button is pressed. I tried researching it, but everything I found was talking about how to add a new row to a table view using a button on the table view; that's not what I'm looking for. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, I'm using navigation controllers because I want the table view to be presented modally, as if it was sliding up from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You probably want a User class of sorts that contains all of the text they 'favorite'. Then when they view their favorites it pulls the text from that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table view is data driven, that is its contents are created form a NSArray or similar. You are probably familiar with UITableViewDatasource which (at minimum) queries the data for the number of items to be displayed and the content for the cells. So all your button needs to do is add a label (most simply, a NSString *) to an array. The table view is created from the content in the array - basically all you do is `[tableView reloadData]` and the new content is shown in the table.

If the table view is in another view controller, make the array a property on that view controller. When you have built the array on one controller and you want to switch to the controller with the table view, just set the array on the table view's view controller after creating it but before pushing it onto the navigation stack.

Comment: Okay, I followed you until the end. I made my button add a string to a mutable array. Then I added a NSLog statement to make sure that it worked, and it did. However, when I tried to populate the table view I didn't see anything, and the array appeared to be null. I'm thinking I probably left out the last paragraph of your explanation, but it's still a little confusing to me. Am I creating another array on the tableViewController and then setting that with the initial array, or...? I'm not sure...

Comment: You just need to be sure that your new view controller - the one with the table view - has its array property populated with the list of things that you want to display in the table. The UITableViewDatasource methods will populate the table from this array. In the new view controller the property should be a NSArray because it isn't going to change in that view controller. The old view controller has a mutable array as you mention. Do something like newViewController.tableItemsSourceArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.myMutableArray];

Comment: Last question: So where am I adding that last bit of code, the newViewController.tableItemsSourceArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.myMutableArray]; ? Is it when the user clicks the button, or in the prepareForSegue or something else?

Comment: Right. If using segues, do it in prepareForSeque with the target being the destination view controller. If using another method (navigation controller push) then do it when you create the new view controller.